# Add the X values in Json with respect to Image

Tags: javascript, json

In a Json, there are multiple image sources as **"src" : "image.png",** , **"src" : "image2.png",**

For image.png , right now i am fetching **X value as "40"**  [3rd position in below image]

For image2.png , right now i am fetching **X value as "100"**  [6th position in below image]

**Requirement** :

Instead of that,  i need to add 1st (10) + 3rd (40) + 4th (50) positions values and fetch **final X value** for `"src" : "image.png"`, as **100** [10+40+50] and

`"src" : "image1.png"` = 1st (10) + 6th (100) + 7th (105) positions & final value of **X is 215**....

[image]

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/zbKaEJ

```js
let jsonData = {
  
  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 10,   
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 20,          
          "y" : 30,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 40,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 50,            
              "src" : "image.png",
              "y" : 60,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {
              
              "x" : 70,
              "y" : 80,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 90,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 100,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 105,             
              "src" : "image2.png",
              "y" : 110,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 120,
              "y" : 130,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 140,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 150,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};


function getData(data) {
var dataObj = {};
let layer1 = data.layers;
let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

  for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
  var x = layer2[i].x;
 

    var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
    
    document.write("src :" + src);
 document.write("<br>");
 
 document.write("x:" + x);
 document.write("<br>");
 
 
  }
  
}
getData(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a recursive function you can find all the `src` and its corresponding summed `x` values.

Below is a crude example. Refactor as you see fit.

```js
let jsonData = {
  

  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 10,   
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 20,          
          "y" : 30,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 40,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 50,            
              "src" : "image.png",
              "y" : 60,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {
              
              "x" : 70,
              "y" : 80,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 90,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 100,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 105,             
              "src" : "image2.png",
              "y" : 110,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 120,
              "y" : 130,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 140,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 150,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};

function getAllSrc(layers){
  let arr = [];
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    if(layer.src){
      arr.push({src: layer.src, x: layer.x});
    }
    else if(layer.layers){
      let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
      if(newArr.length > 0){
        newArr.forEach(({src, x}) =>{
          arr.push({src, x: (layer.x + x)});
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

function getData(data) {
  let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
  for (let {src, x} of arr){
  document.write("src :" + src);
 document.write("<br>");
 
 document.write("x:" + x);
 document.write("<br>");
  }   
  
}
getData(jsonData);
```

Here is the CodePen for the same: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wmpvre

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using **recursion**. While going though nested obj you could parent `x` value each item in `layers` and check if the element in `layers` have `src` property add the previous `x` value to it.

```js
let jsonData = {
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 10,   
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 20,          
          "y" : 30,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 40,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 50,            
              "src" : "image.png",
              "y" : 60,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {
              
              "x" : 70,
              "y" : 80,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 90,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 100,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 105,             
              "src" : "image2.png",
              "y" : 110,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 120,
              "y" : 130,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 140,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 150,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};


function changeData(obj,x=0){
  if(obj.src) obj.x += x;
  if(obj.layers){
    for(const item of obj.layers){
      changeData(item,x+obj.x || 0);
    }
  }
}
changeData(jsonData);

function showData(obj){

  if(obj.src) document.body.innerHTML += `src:${obj.src}<br>
  x:${obj.x}<br>`;
  if(obj.layers){
    for(let i of obj.layers) showData(i)
  }
}
showData(jsonData);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, As the other answer gave answer before 3 minutes, i accepted that answer....

Comment: @vickeycolors Time doesn't matter in giving answer. The thing which matters is short and efficient and I think mine code is better. And if you was not to accept my answer you shouldn't have asked me that much help.well if you think his code is better so no problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution with recursion and mutation. You can cloneDeep the array before if you don't want to mutate it directly.

```js
// Code
function recursion(obj, currentX = 0) {
  if(obj.src) obj.x = currentX
  else if(obj.layers) {
    obj.layers.forEach(subObj => recursion(subObj, (currentX + subObj.x))) 
  } 
}

// Data
let jsonData = {
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 10,   
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 20,          
          "y" : 30,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 40,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 50,            
              "src" : "image.png",
              "y" : 60,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {
              
              "x" : 70,
              "y" : 80,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 90,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 100,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 105,             
              "src" : "image2.png",
              "y" : 110,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 120,
              "y" : 130,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 140,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 150,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};

// Use
recursion(jsonData)

console.log(jsonData)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let jsonData = {


  "layers": [{
    "x": 10,
    "layers": [{
        "x": 20,
        "y": 30,
        "name": "L2a"
      },
      {
        "x": 40,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 50,
            "src": "image.png",
            "y": 60,
            "name": "L2b-1"
          },
          {

            "x": 70,
            "y": 80,
            "name": "L2b-2"
          }
        ],
        "y": 90,
        "name": "user_image_1"
      },
      {
        "x": 100,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 105,
            "src": "image2.png",
            "y": 110,
            "name": "L2C-1"
          },
          {
            "x": 120,
            "y": 130,
            "name": "L2C-2"
          }
        ],
        "y": 140,
        "name": "L2"
      }
    ],
    "y": 150,
    "name": "L1"
  }]
};


function getData(data) {
  var dataObj = {};
  let layer1 = data.layers;
  let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;
  let y = layer1[0].x;
  for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
    var x = y;
    x += layer2[i].x;
    x += layer2[i].layers[0].x;

    var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;

    document.write("src :" + src);
    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("x:" + x);
    document.write("<br>");


  }

}
getData(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is My Solution. Check this out

```js
let jsonData = {
  

    "layers" : [
      {
        "x" : 10,   //
        "layers" : [
          {
            "x" : 20,          
            "y" : 30,         
            "name" : "L2a"
          },
          {
            "x" : 40,    //     
            "layers" : [
              {
                "x" : 50,      //      
                "src" : "image.png",
                "y" : 60,              
                "name" : "L2b-1"
              },
              {
                
                "x" : 70,
                "y" : 80,             
                "name" : "L2b-2"
              }
            ],
            "y" : 90,         
            "name" : "user_image_1"
          },
          {
            "x" : 100,         
            "layers" : [
              {
                "x" : 105,             
                "src" : "image2.png",
                "y" : 110,             
                "name" : "L2C-1"
              },
              {            
                "x" : 120,
                "y" : 130,            
                "name" : "L2C-2"
              }
            ],
            "y" : 140,         
            "name" : "L2"
          }
        ],
        "y" : 150,      
        "name" : "L1"
      }
    ]
};

var dataObj = [];
var x, src;
  
  
function getData(data) {

    let layer1 = data.layers;

    for(var i = 0; i < layer1.length; i++){

  

        if(x === 0){
          x = layer1[i].x;
          continue;
        }
            
        x = layer1[i].x;
        

        if(typeof layer1[i].layers !== 'undefined')
            createOutput(layer1[i].layers);


    }

    return dataObj;

    
}

function createOutput(dataArray){

    
    if(typeof dataArray === 'undefined'){

        dataObj.push({x: x, src: src});
        x = 0;
        getData(jsonData);
 return;

    }
        

    dataArray.forEach(element => {

        if(typeof element.layers !== 'undefined' || typeof element.src !== 'undefined'){

            x += element.x;
            src = element.src;
            createOutput(element.layers);

        }

        
    }) 
    
    
    

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getData(jsonData)));
```